# eth.contract gives undefined error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have a private ethereum system with a couple of nodes. I'm trying to deploy a contract on one of them.
To begin with, I am trying to just deploy a sample contract from the net. This is what I'm using:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract sample {
 string public name = "ZeonLab";
 function set(string _name) {
    name = _name;
 }

 function get() constant returns (string) {
   return name;
 }
}
```

I compile this with the solc compiler and get the ABI and bytecode by running solc --abi and solc --bin respectively. I then try to deploy the contract on geth as follows:
geth console

```
> var test = eth.contract('abi text above')
```

It however gives me an undefined error. in fact, instead of the ABI text from above, if I just do: `var test = eth.contract('test')`, I still see an error.

I read somewhere that we need to do: `var testTxt = JSON.parse('abi text above')`
However, that did not work either.

From the error, it looks like there may be an issue with recognizing eth.contract itself. When I type eth on the console, I see that contract is one of the options.

Any suggestions on what could b wrong.

thx - anand

Comment: i don't have the exact answer to your question. but i have alternative option but you can use truffle for deployment .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I will try truffle.

In the meantime, I also figured out that this (so-called) error does not matter.
In fact, when I type: var test = eth.contract('abi text above')
and I type test after that, I see the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should solve your problem.

```
var contract_name = new web3.eth.Contract('YOUR ABI', 'YOUR CONTRACT ADDRESS')
```